# How to use start and end restrictions in WebStorm search (and other JetBrains IDEs)?

Tags: regex, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to create a regex that will "unwrap" code that is quoted, in parentheses, brackets, or braces.

I have a regex that [should work](https://regex101.com/r/tEwrmM/3):

```
^["'({[](.+)["')}\]]$
```

The ^ and $ are important to prevent inner characters from breaking the match.

In WebStorm (2018.1.6) The regex works without the ^ and $:

```
["'({[](.+)["')}\]]
```

[image: Working RegEx]

but fails if I add the start and end restriction:

```
^["'({[](.+)["')}\]]$
```

[image]

Is there a trick to do this? Is it a problem with combining "Regex" and "In Selection" modes for Search/Replace? Could it be a bug?

Any help?

Comment: The `^` and `$` in your current regex doesn't make any sense unless the match will necessarily match the *entire line* - they're start-of-line and end-of-line anchors. Try pasting in your real code instead: https://regex101.com/r/tEwrmM/2 (note that most of those characters in the character set don't actually need to be escaped)

Comment: You can't use '^' and ''$' since you are only matching part of the line (in the images)! There are characters before and after the match, that will make full line fail.

Comment: @PoulBak,  thats what i meant by 'problem with combining "Regex" and "In Selection" modes'... I guess I expected that if I have "In Selection" checked that it will consider the beginning and end of the _selection_ as the 'start-of-line and end-of-line'

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks for the hint that i was over-escaping and for the fix on regex101